# Why is my for-in loop is looping double the size of my array?

Tags: javascript, dom, loops, for-in-loop

I am using a for-in loop to iterate over an array of two elements, but it is like its looping twice.

I have an example here: http://jsbin.com/etoyac/8/

Comment: You should not use `for .. in` to iterate on arrays.

Comment: @bažmegakapa ... and you shouldn't expect NodeList objects to act like arrays :-)

Comment: Both of you are correct and I am being rather silly :)

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, that makes the whole picture :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the result returned from `getElementsByTagName` isn't a simple array — it's a **NodeList** and it's "live".  Updates you make to the DOM are reflected in the list immediately.

You can use the "slice" method on the Array prototype to turn the NodeList into an array:

```
var slideArr = [].slice.call(slides, 0);
```

Also you should iterate through the array (or the NodeList for that matter) with a numeric index:

```
for (var slideIndex = 0; slideIndex < slideArr.length; ++slideIndex) {
```